# largest singular value NumPy `ndarray`

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, svd

I have a large bidimensional `ndarray`, `A` and I want to compute the SVD retrieving largest eigenvalue and associated eigenvector pair. Looking at NumPy docs it seems that NumPy can compute the complete SVD only (`numpy.linalg.svd`), while SciPy has method that does exactly what I need (`scipy.sparse.linalg.svds`), but with sparse matrices and I don't want to perform a conversion of `A`, since it would require additional computational time.

Until now, I have used SciPy `svds` directly on the `A` however the documentation discourages to pass `ndarray`s to these methods.

Is there a way to perform this task with a method that accepts `ndarray` objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `svds` works with your dense `A` array, then continue to use it.  You don't need to convert it to anything.  `svds` does all the adaptation that it needs.

It's documentation says

> A : {sparse matrix, LinearOperator}
>           Array to compute the SVD on, of shape (M, N)

But what is a `LinearOperator`? It is a wrapper around something that can perform a matrix product.  For a dense array `A.dot` qualifies.

Look at the code for `svds`.  The first thing is does is `A = np.asarray(A)` if `A` isn't already a Linear Operator or sparse matrix.  Then it grabs `A.dot` and `(hemetianA).dot` and makes a new LinearOperator.

There's nothing special about a sparse matrix in this function.  All that matters is having a compatible matrix product.

Look at these times:

```
In [358]: A=np.eye(10)
In [359]: Alg=splg.aslinearoperator(A)
In [360]: Am=sparse.csr_matrix(A)
In [361]: timeit splg.svds(A)
1000 loops, best of 3: 541 µs per loop
In [362]: timeit splg.svds(Alg)
1000 loops, best of 3: 964 µs per loop
In [363]: timeit splg.svds(Am)
1000 loops, best of 3: 939 µs per loop
```

Direct use of `A` is fastest.  The conversions don't help, even when they are outside of the timing loop.